# Computational Complexity of Equational Logic

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, proof-theory, universal-algebra, computer-assisted-proofs

Equational logic uses a surprisingly small set of axioms to prove all algebraic identities (algebraic in the sense of universal algebra, so things like field theory fall beyond this scope). This makes proving an identity in algebra seem pretty easy, an experience which matches experience, where usually you can find a proof quickly or even instantly, whereas disproving an identity can involve constructing a complex counterexample. I was wondering if this can be demonstrated formally. Specifically, suppose we have an efficient algorithm for doing equational logic. Given an algebraic identity consisting of $n$ symbols, what can we say about maximum length of time the algorithm will take to prove the identity asymptotically? Note that I am only interested in identities. There is no disproof in equational logic, so the algorithm will never halt on a non-identity.

Comment: Judging by the plethora of ring-theoretic identities that have short proofs using ideal theory, and _no known equational proofs at all_, even though we have plenty of computational power to search for them and we know they must exist, I'd suggest that a.) your "experience which matches experience" is in fact highly atypical; b.) the bounds, should they exist, are massive.

Comment: Also relevant: the work of [Hrubeš and Tzameret](https://users.math.cas.cz/~hrubes/PDFs/IddoEqSys.pdf), which tackles an easier problem,

Comment: If you'd like explicit examples of ring-theoretic identities with no known equational proofs, Martin Brandenburg is an expert on the topic, and he frequents this site, so I'm sure he'll be along with some examples momentarily. In the meantime, I have one from my own work in group theory: an equational proof of $[a\iota(x),b\iota(y),c\iota(z)] \vdash [\iota(x),\iota(y),\iota(z)]$ where $a,b,c$ are constant symbols and $\iota$ is a subgroup embedding remains elusive; I gave an equational proof of $[a\iota(x), b\iota(y)] \vdash[\iota(x),\iota(y)]$ in 2.15 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.01773).

Comment: @Z. A. K. I don't think we're talking about the same thing. By identity, I mean an algebraic equation using operations in a given variety of algebras, that holds in every such algebra. We know that equational logic is complete, so identities will always have proofs in equational logic. Therefore, the bounds on asymptotic computation time definitely exist, as asymptotically efficient algorithms always exist (this is why computational complexity theory is a thing).

Comment: No, I'm well aware of the completeness result that you mention, and I can assure you that we're talking about exactly the same thing. Producing equational proofs is incredibly difficult. You can phrase the problem I give above as an identity question in a variety of universal algebras. Jacobson's theorem, with fixed $n$ and uniform $x$, is also a problem of this sort: it has plenty of known proofs, but no known equational ones for most $n$.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I was just confused by the "should they exist" and the subgroup embedding.

Comment: @Z.A.K. Although that said, my understanding is that Brandernberg has done some recent work on this - see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.05301).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Indeed, whcih is why my first comment said that I'd rather wait for him to give the most up-to-date examples of ring identites eith no known short proofs :)

Comment: I am interested in examples for abstract proofs of identities with or without known equational proofs. @Z.A.K. What is the abstract proof for Proposition 2.15 that you have cited above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: equational logic is as powerful as computation in general, so there is no computable bound for the time needed to prove equational problems.

One way to make this precise is the following: fix some complete algorithm $A$ for proving equations from finite sets of equations. Then there is no computable function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $A$ terminates with a proof on all provable inputs of size $n$ in $f(n)$ steps. Suppose such a function would exist. Let $\langle S, R\rangle$ be a finite presentation of a group with an undecidable word problem. Then the following would be a decision algorithm for the word problem in this group: given an input word $w$ let $n$ be the size of the axioms of groups plus the size of $\langle S,R \rangle$ plus the size of $w$. Compute $k=f(n)$. Run $A$ for $k$ many steps trying to prove $w = e$ from the axioms of groups and $\langle S, R\rangle$. If $A$ outputs a proof answer with yes, otherwise answer with no.